# Why does my working directory in R does not work?

Tags: r, directory

I have tried setting a different working directory in R (am a complete newbie) and this I have tried, first seeing the current directory then trying to change it:

```
> getwd()
[1] "C:/Users/Gebruiker/Documents"
> setwd("C:\Users\Gebruiker\Desktop\R")
Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string starting "C:\U"
> setwd("C:/Users/Gebruiker/Desktop/R")
> getwd
function () 
.Internal(getwd())
<bytecode: 0x000001a1b3cf8d18>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

I don't understand the error about hex digits. I had copy pasted the directory within the ""
Then I tried typing with / in stead of \ same as it looks in the current directory.
But then I get this info about internal bytecode et cetera. And when trying to getwd this is what I see. So how to set it right?

I already did, see the above?

Comment: You need to include the parentheses when you call `getwd()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A backslash is an the escape character.  Basically it's how you get things you can't easily put into strings from a keyboard so it starts a 'code' that will end up being one of those characters.  You either need to use two backslashes in a string if you want a backslash like `"C:\\Users"` or just do what you did and use forward slashes.

The reason you got the output on your last call to `getwd` is that you never actually called it.  You typed `getwd` but you need to actually call the function like `getwd()`